# How to run application when double click drive it contains in C#

Tags: c#

In C# i want to make a application which will automatically run when the drive/folder(which contains the application) is doubleclicked.

How can i do that in C#??

Comment: So you want to integrate this with Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

For drives you can use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autorun.inf. For folders you have to create some deamon which will observe the behaviour of user and then when some folder is clicked trigger proper application. Imo, you cannot do that from stand allone application which just lay in some folder and waiting that somebody click root folder.

Comment: +1 However, Autorun.inf are blocked by many AV engines and Microsoft has released patches that disable automatically launching applications based on Autorun.inf since this was a main source of PC infection due to infection pen drives.